# How to safely alter Magento category attributes

Tags: module, attributes, database, setup-script

I understand how to write setup scripts through a custom module. However, if you directly alter something like `catalog_category` by adding a new attribute, is there a way to then safely remove it in the future, if need be?

I.e. is there way to uninstall a custom module of which has altered core tables?

I'm just a bit wary of editing them if its best practise to stay away all together!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding [this module](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageTrashApp). It both helps with uninstallation and understanding the way in which it is achieved (By looking through to module), so doubly helpful!